How to merge two transaction instructions into one transaction in Python?
Im trying to make a transaction with two swaps in it that looks like this:
Swap 1 Instructions: {'tokenLedgerInstruction': None, 'computeBudgetInstructions': [{'programId': 'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111', 'accounts': [], 'data': 'AsBcFQA='}, {'programId': 'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111', 'accounts': [], 'data': 'AwQXAQAAAAAA'}], 'setupInstructions': [{'programId': 'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '11111111111111111111111111111111', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'AQ=='}, {'programId': '11111111111111111111111111111111', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}], 'data': 'AgAAAKCGAQAAAAAA'}, {'programId': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}], 'data': 'EQ=='}], 'swapInstruction': {'programId': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '91bUbswo6Di8235jAPwim1At4cPZLbG2pkpneyqKg4NQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'Gjmjory7TWKJXD2Jc6hKzAG991wWutFhtbXudzJqgx3p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '8mqfwrYuqk1rtLLQNcKcbavz6nYCMMRr7aovedGvEbc6', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'D8cy77BBepLMngZx6ZukaTff5hCt1HrWyKk3Hnd9oitf', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5ehutprzjw4a8DJXeqvxc78oVZ6wdtZ3fRbNzxYFe93x', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'GR5jcNVS1HCBgPz8PqVqpGwY426Dq5oXZ8NEGZSC6QjP', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'AYHRHVNoocfjNRx84NG6oYGDGwizoLEnSaML5R9JmyjA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '91bUbswo6Di8235jAPwim1At4cPZLbG2pkpneyqKg4NQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '85DaXurWGcHgGXXjgK8VHrxsAiQYo8HzND5xjdPe9nLH', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5VfDUazQoy7bwsMyN4c14hx7VLTAz6X5CKjXSxYWCCDS', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'D1ZN9Wj1fRSUQfCjhvnu1hqDMT7hzjzBBpi12nVniYD6', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'FyYGSECmh2YNTRbNyXMxs7xTjG5s3uRCdDgtJ3hYdR6S', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '9JYZhF6jpUxczbXG7F6iZapTweVJ3V8XyKwQaXTs46fP', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4eX9XvtWTgTMoMLD7XcXXR81rKknnwFU7kE6wLVm7rTK', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'AFbX8oGjGpmVFywbVouvhQSRmiW2aR1mohfahi4Y2AdB', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '85DaXurWGcHgGXXjgK8VHrxsAiQYo8HzND5xjdPe9nLH', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'FTLdbWVi1FoA1wiT3sPJETqSqkxM7UqemdHt9CSscyiw', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '4oDAMdDDm2nuH6n2bVffAE2CNCdtvaWQiyz6n8rRgYNL', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '3wgqpehmh1i4zCnVzA7FNnAR9EYpZf7MPTvomqZcjUbR', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '9qC9u6TEWM4Tv3xaMw6ypvdrbLyvcBKwfi9GSqwLceyF', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'HGZK8mRbASEBpSeZ9sWaPwLpAopsrhH8G8EomaM6fT6g', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '6BjZ2LEebPXkNGVbR2c6YWpdSZoy9eiQynJobxPuHGn', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '8DcEAD3UNtp8FXpUAH77mKtXK3XxsdF5JUNnUAPYt73e', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GaXifgJsU9UfKqmRBcTfLVmG9DCwQDEavskaZ2Q7Vr5v', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '7h8cu7FqRE3MpN9hPreCzS2qYJNDxMJfBC7Are9rMc3i', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5NLeMabMyuJQUbvXNfVyUPbtYKwTXBesfmFmDswbgqUz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4oDAMdDDm2nuH6n2bVffAE2CNCdtvaWQiyz6n8rRgYNL', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'Gjmjory7TWKJXD2Jc6hKzAG991wWutFhtbXudzJqgx3p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'wSCbM0HWnIEFAwAAACZkAAEvAQBkAQIHZAIDoIYBAAAAAAB6XQAAAAAAADIAAA=='}, 'cleanupInstruction': {'programId': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'CQ=='}, 'otherInstructions': [], 'addressLookupTableAddresses': ['43FGSSzDd2qAfHdFrbcSxu7MPmxZrHhK5kCVjvT5KsWo', 'Ae1Hmgnvnh7S3SH2TfFdkbh8kynFxXb2sDKG3TeSvXwN', '2ngDk9t5BoWzZRTKFweZmsu7Cho8iBjK5u7MsqEsz1vX'], 'prioritizationFeeLamports': 99999, 'computeUnitLimit': 1400000, 'prioritizationType': {'computeBudget': {'microLamports': 71428, 'estimatedMicroLamports': 280000}}, 'simulationSlot': None, 'dynamicSlippageReport': None, 'simulationError': None}
Swap 2 Instructions: {'tokenLedgerInstruction': None, 'computeBudgetInstructions': [{'programId': 'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111', 'accounts': [], 'data': 'AsBcFQA='}, {'programId': 'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111', 'accounts': [], 'data': 'AwQXAQAAAAAA'}], 'setupInstructions': [{'programId': 'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '11111111111111111111111111111111', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'AQ=='}], 'swapInstruction': {'programId': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '8mqfwrYuqk1rtLLQNcKcbavz6nYCMMRr7aovedGvEbc6', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'Gjmjory7TWKJXD2Jc6hKzAG991wWutFhtbXudzJqgx3p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '91bUbswo6Di8235jAPwim1At4cPZLbG2pkpneyqKg4NQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'D8cy77BBepLMngZx6ZukaTff5hCt1HrWyKk3Hnd9oitf', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'FKZsMbwsXCi3HX7X3NpNF1cJSSTpnAyTcKPW7MD3orBx', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '29rBmyXzjjF87KMSg8Hmgbi8qpAmXffjy8Ay92NU7NQ2', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '7Wi59ZiKjhLPz4HjBTygTqoT69oMTRJh5aWtPCYP59d1', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'Gjmjory7TWKJXD2Jc6hKzAG991wWutFhtbXudzJqgx3p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'CeuxCEs6k8LMsM8q4F4JEkXK2G5QYXYUUU5Q5XE26D66', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '3NZ9JMVBmGAqocybic2c7LQCJScmgsAZ6vQqTDzcqmJh', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '8aakM2ZtoG3UVREHzkpEYNughAVy3CkY3Tf4ZmrpznjG', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'D1ZN9Wj1fRSUQfCjhvnu1hqDMT7hzjzBBpi12nVniYD6', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '6qKY1Ge6CkuDr1MBxvqbhWpiNsLCWhhfkPhnHjJ6otZQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '9bArUwcXmmkYKAWhRFDubWG3UUBDdt1FFekvDcjvSUeT', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'PERPHjGBqRHArX4DySjwM6UJHiR3sWAatqfdBS2qQJu', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CeuxCEs6k8LMsM8q4F4JEkXK2G5QYXYUUU5Q5XE26D66', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'C5eU28PS4qSH6NpcP1UtHUCHWYNmUZXGkx7Q4HS6PVUj', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'AVzP2GeRmqGphJsMxWoqjpUifPpCret7LqWhD8NWQK49', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'H4ND9aYttUVLFmNypZqLjZ52FYiGvdEB45GmwNoKEjTj', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5BUwFW4nRbftYTDMbgxykoFWqWHPzahFSNAaaaJtVKsq', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '5Pv3gM9JrFFH883SWAhvJC9RPYmo8UNxuFtv5bMMALkm', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '4HBbPx9QJdjJ7GUe6bsiJjGybvfpDhQMMPXP1UEa7VT5', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4cSM2e6rvbGQUFiJbqytoVMi5GgghSMr8LwVrT9VPSPo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'FgpXg2J3TzSs7w3WGYYE7aWePdrxBVLCXSxmAKnCZNtZ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '27G8MtK7VtTcCHkpASjSDdkWWYfoqT6ggEuKidVJidD4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '37hJBDnntwqhGbK7L6M1bLyvccj4u55CCUiLPdYkiqBN', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'PERPHjGBqRHArX4DySjwM6UJHiR3sWAatqfdBS2qQJu', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '7xS2gz2bTp3fwCC7knJvUWTEU9Tycczu6VhJYKgi1wdz', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'AQCGyheWPLeo6Qp9WpYS9m3Qj479t7R636N9ey1rEjEn', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5Pv3gM9JrFFH883SWAhvJC9RPYmo8UNxuFtv5bMMALkm', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'G18jKKXQwBbrHeiK3C9MRXhkHsLHf7XgCSisykV46EZa', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4vkNeXiYEUizLdrpdPS1eC2mccyM4NUPRtERrk6ZETkk', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '39cWjvHrpHNz2SbXv6ME4NPhqBDBd4KsjUYv5JkHEAJU', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '5URYohbPy32nxK1t3jAHVNfdWY2xTubHiFvLrE3VhXEp', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4HBbPx9QJdjJ7GUe6bsiJjGybvfpDhQMMPXP1UEa7VT5', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'A28T5pKtscnhDo6C1Sz786Tup88aTjt8uyKewjVvPrGk', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'AGW7q2a3WxCzh5TB2Q6yNde1Nf41g3HLaaXdybz7cbBU', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '7UVimffxr9ow1uXYxsr4LHAcV58mLzhmwaeKvJ1pjLiE', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '42amVS4KgzR9rA28tkVYqVXjq9Qa8dcZQMbH5EYFX6XC', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4cSM2e6rvbGQUFiJbqytoVMi5GgghSMr8LwVrT9VPSPo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'Dpw1EAVrSB1ibxiDQyTAW6Zip3J4Btk2x4SgApQCeFbX', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'HT2PLQBcG5EiCcNSaMHAjSgd9F98ecpATbk4Sk5oYuM', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'J2Gsg3xTDjM8UZjKdEqzBeDwitHb2Ux6TSBX5RzsE42r', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '2FbyRT4aUAHVpEfFnK7Yw2kf7jXhHwkqKRvpXUcDpW2Z', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'At9UqZTwnCY84Q4z47zv3T3VtZeypgo2v6GvGhFRafJJ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'C5eU28PS4qSH6NpcP1UtHUCHWYNmUZXGkx7Q4HS6PVUj', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '91bUbswo6Di8235jAPwim1At4cPZLbG2pkpneyqKg4NQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '27G8MtK7VtTcCHkpASjSDdkWWYfoqT6ggEuKidVJidD4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': '4ATLvpodvjWkVxb8w4FrK3L3PYQDXiSYyAjfSSUJH5sw', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'CapuXNQoDviLvU1PxFiizLgPNQCxrsag1uMeyk6zLVps', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'D1ZN9Wj1fRSUQfCjhvnu1hqDMT7hzjzBBpi12nVniYD6', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'LBUZKhRxPF3XUpBCjp4YzTKgLccjZhTSDM9YuVaPwxo', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}, {'pubkey': 'DdDmffymXFP7WG1MrJL1cbCEssCtinJsp7Ug4fhzdRtQ', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': '6gF335d3eXyHCYRAXAa9KzzFDUPAT37qbq5A7W8qgtZH', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'wSCbM0HWnIEFAwAAACZkAAE0ZAECJmQCA3pdAAAAAAAA34kBAAAAAAAyAAA='}, 'cleanupInstruction': {'programId': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'accounts': [{'pubkey': 'CB4MtxsYJX6XPpfPjEzghhRB626PcAXkVCaEqRmqrdDe', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': False, 'isWritable': True}, {'pubkey': 'GzP7rLxy4PexgKvjkkBhxQ5qFBRAvAweyNvzEpgBWr8p', 'isSigner': True, 'isWritable': False}], 'data': 'CQ=='}, 'otherInstructions': [], 'addressLookupTableAddresses': ['G4hCVUU4y4vUYsA5zk8co6KuetjuaN9sUBQjoHpcXNDr', 'Captu1tRmk2rbVAeyMSCe3rdyehdFFNv1DGZpNMEk7xW', 'Ak38egnSBV9mHL4NUXupB6FASTyBYjt4qe4tGkcziv99'], 'prioritizationFeeLamports': 99999, 'computeUnitLimit': 1400000, 'prioritizationType': {'computeBudget': {'microLamports': 71428, 'estimatedMicroLamports': 280000}}, 'simulationSlot': None, 'dynamicSlippageRepor

Can someone help me to send in one transaction two swap in python ?
Thank you !

The sample transactions look like they come from some third-party API, since the transaction format is not standard. Maybe the API provider has some docs on how to do that? Or you can provide more info about where you got them from.
